# Confused on UK to US travel in regards to testing

Tags: usa, uk

Traveling from UK to USA on 13th September with a layover in Amsterdam.

On the way back it's USA to UK with a layover in Amsterdam.

Traveling with my US wife (I'm a British citizen).  Both fully vaccinated.

As far as I can tell, we need a negative viral test to fly to USA (and to complete the negative attestation form) and that's it.

However on the way back to enter UK, we'll need a pre departure test, then another test on day 2 and to complete the passenger locator form.

I'm very confused on where to book all these tests since the CDC website just says an antigen test is sufficient (but how do I prove the result, over text?) And the UK government website has no information on where to complete a test in the USA before we fly back.

I would appreciate some help since it's bugging me out if somebody who has traveled from UK to USA in recent weeks could chip in.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

The rules for the Covid test required prior to embarking on a flight to England are found [here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-testing-for-people-travelling-to-england). The rules for the test for flying to Wales are identical. My understanding is that essentially any "proper" Covid test will meet the rules, and then you just need a test certificate containing the information listed in the rules.

I've recently returned to Wales from a trip abroad, and for the pre-departure test I got tested by a GP and had them stamp and sign a test certificate I had prepared just following the UK rules. There wasn't any kind of standard certificate I could have gotten from my GP, and the one I drafted was accepted just fine.

It is very plausible that this test certificate will never be seen by any British official. Instead, it is going to be checked by the airline that's flying you to the UK. (You could be checked on arrival, so keep the certificate + passenger locator form confirmation ready.) If you are concerned about getting the test certificate accepted, you could try to check with the airline.

Answer (score -3):

It's a pain in the neck.

You just need to research test centers at the places where you will be and hope for the best. Testing is offered in many airports but typically at a very hefty price and the timing is tricky.

There are plenty of public and private test sites but they all have all different rules, prices, appointment/documentation requirements , turn-around times, and availability.

There are no standards on documenting test results. Everybody makes up their own format. You should get a paper or electronic certificate with name, date of birth, maybe ID #, type of test, some test method/type detail and the facility/doctor who administered it.

Example: I had a documentation for an Antigen test that was accepted by one German Public Health Office  but rejected by another. These are neighboring districts in the same state. I moved to a hotel one mile away and I was good.

The most annoying part (IMO) of this is, that it punishes responsible people. Getting a fully compliant test is a pain in the neck, photoshopping a good looking test results takes 10 minutes or less (WHICH I DO NOT CONDONE).